# Primefaces and circular Carousel

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, carousel

I'm using Primefaces 3.2 with Tomcat 7.0.23 and JSF 2.0
i'm using the  component.

```
 <p:carousel id="aCarousel" value="#{BBCarousel.carouselItems}" var="carouselItem"  
              autoPlayInterval="3000"
              rows="4" vertical="true" circular="true" pageLinks="0" headerText="Informations"  >      

    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="images/minilogo.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <a href="#">#{carouselItem.item_title}</a>
      <span class="cat">Category: #{carouselItem.item_cat}</span>
    </div>
  </p:carousel>
```

When the carousel reaches the last carousel item, the carousel slides to (move up) the first element.. instead, i would like that the last item to be attached to the first item, in a "circular way", without a break.. so i get a continuous scrolling effect.. 
I hope I have been clear..
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at Firebug I see that the carousel is mostly a div and a hidden input that have coordinate values.

```
<div id="slideShow" class="ui-carousel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 404px;">
<div class="ui-carousel-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
<div class="ui-carousel-viewport" style="width: 404px; height: 253px;">
<ul style="left: -808px;">
<li class="ui-carousel-item ui-widget-content ui-corner-all photo">
<img id="slideShow:j_idt15" alt="" src="/showcase/images/nature1.jpg;jsessionid=A181FD9A4E1990E40E09B3743EB2EE61">
</li>
<li class="ui-carousel-item ui-widget-content ui-corner-all photo">
<li class="ui-carousel-item ui-widget-content ui-corner-all photo">
<li class="ui-carousel-item ui-widget-content ui-corner-all photo">
</ul>
</div>
<input id="slideShow_first" type="hidden" value="2" name="slideShow_first">
</div>
```

These values are changing at the autoPlayInterval which looks like a jQuery script is being invoked to move the image and perform an effect while doing so.

I don't see anything in the Primefaces documentation that suggest the unwanted autoplay effect can be changed.  I don't think this is possible without modifying the Primefaces code.